# Won´t connect with database

Tags: php, database

I tried to make questionnaire, but it just does not connect with my database, which is weird, because in other php almost the same connection works. Can you please help?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pohlavi'])) {
    if (!isset($_POST['platforma']) || !isset($_POST['ano']) || !isset($_POST['nazor']) || $_POST['platforma'] = "" || $_POST['nazor'] = "" || $_POST['ano'] = "") {
        die("Nastala chyba, musíte vyplnit všechny pole! Dotazník nebyl odeslán.");
    } else {
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'adress', 'password', 'czseznamka');
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO dotaznik (pohlavi, platforma, ano, nazor) VALUES ('" . $_POST['pohlavi'] . "', '" . $_POST['platforma'] . "', '" . $_POST['ano'] . "' , '" . $_POST['nazor'] . "');");
        echo '<span style="text-align:center;color:green;font-size:30px;"> Dotazník odeslán</span>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what is output of `var_dump($conn)`

Comment: You need to tell mysqli to throw exceptions:

Comment: whats the output getting now

Comment: always check for any errors: `if($conn->connect_error){echo $conn->connect_error;}` before and after query execution.

Comment: make sure the order of arguments is host,user,password,database

Comment: I would guess that you spelt `adress` wrongly in you connection parameters!

Answer (score 0):

Try With following enabling error

```
if (isset($_POST['pohlavi'])) {
     if (!isset($_POST['platforma']) || !isset($_POST['ano']) || !isset($_POST['nazor']) || $_POST['platforma'] = "" || $_POST['nazor'] = "" || $_POST['ano'] = "") {
         mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

     try {
         $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbname') ;
         $connection->query("INSERT INTO dotaznik (pohlavi, platforma, ano, nazor) VALUES ('" . $_POST['pohlavi'] . "', '" . $_POST['platforma'] . "', '" . $_POST['ano'] . "' , '" . $_POST['nazor'] . "');");

      } catch (Exception $e ) {
         echo "Service unavailable";
         echo "message: " . $e->message;   
         exit;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully nobody is daft enough to leave there `root` SuperUser account without a password of any sort. You dont know anybody that foolish do you?